# JavaScript, difference between date strings

Tags: javascript

I’m aware of doing this with a library in order to find the current date and use an integer to find the next date, but I’m trying to find the number of days between two date strings in this format

```
Date1.value = ‘2022-02-22’;
Date2.value = ‘2022-03-01’;
```

Is there a library I need for this or could I do it with vanilla JS

Comment: What is the expected result? What are `Date1` and `Date2`? If these are `<input type="date">`s, simply do `Date2.valueAsDate - Date1.valueAsDate`.

Answer (score 1):

checkout https://github.com/you-dont-need/You-Dont-Need-Momentjs#difference

```js
let a = Math.ceil(
  (new Date('2022-03-01') - new Date('2022-02-22')) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24
);

console.log(a)
```